# Using trim more than once in an array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, trim

I have a snippet of code where I am trying to parse a longer string with special characters into an array with no spaces or special characters. 

input: name: this is some stuff, name2: this is more stuff

desired output: [name,this is some stuff,name2,this is more stuff]

current output: z.trim isn't a function

```
function parseOrder(custOrder) {
  const custOrderArr = custOrder.split(','); 
  const trimedArr = custOrderArr.map((x) => x.trim());
  const numberArr = trimedArr.map((y) => y.split(':'));
  const processArr = numberArr.map((z) => z.trim());
  console.log(processArr);
}
```

Why does trim work the first time and not the second?

Comment: in some of the iterations your var `z` may not be of type `string`, post your dataset you're working with.

Comment: You're creating an array of arrays (stored in numberArr). Maybe you'd want to take a look at array.flatten or use regex.

Comment: `numberArr` looks like it is going to be an array of arrays of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not trim an array. But you could map the array and trim the values.

This result features [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for preventing arrays with pairs.

```js
function parseOrder(custOrder) {
    return custOrder
        .split(',')
        .flatMap(y => y.split(':').map(x => x.trim()));
}


var input = 'name: this is some stuff, name2: this is more stuff ';

console.log(parseOrder(input));
```

Comment: yup, totally skipped over the fact it was an array of arrays, not just an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `split` by two signs, then `trim` your elements:

```
const result = str.split(/[\:,]+/).map(s => s.trim());
```

An example:

```js
let str = 'test: It is me, test2: it is me 2 ';
console.log(str.split(/[\:,]+/).map(s => s.trim()));
```